# App Tracking Transparency with webview | Flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store-connect, apptrackingtransparency

My flutter app has access to some webviews, each webview opens a different page of the same website that has the cookie banner. I tought that the cookie banner would be enough for apple because the app doesn't actually track users, it's the website that does that.

Apple rejected my App because of this so I'm trying to find a way to incorporate the App Tracking Transparency but I can't find what I should do in the case the user disables the tracking, what is the correct behaviour that the app should have?

If I give the user access to the web do I still need to implement App Tracking Transparency? If not, would giving the option on a corner of the webview be enough or should I make the user choose where to open the pages before the actual webview shows?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed.The only way I have found is to make your webview be displayed is to ask permissions for tracking
You can use this plugin to achieve it.

https://pub.dev/packages/app_tracking_transparency

But probably if you give the option to open the URL into an external web app that could work as well.